# Bivariate Probability PDF

Tags: probability

If the joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by

$$f(x, y) = 24y(1 - x - y)$$

for $x > 0, y > 0, x + y < 1$, and $0$ elsewhere

(A) Sketch Support $(X, Y)$ and find $P(X + Y < .5)$

I am fine with the sketch but I am having trouble with the the probability.

This is what I got:

$$
\int^{0.5}_0 \int^{-x+0.5}_0 (24y - 24xy - 24y^2)\,dy\,dx
$$
From here I keep messing up because I am not getting a number between $0$ and $1$. A detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: The bounds should be from .5 to 0 for the first integral and the 2nd integral should be from -x +.5 to 0.

Comment: They really should be the other way around: from $0$ to $0.5$ for the first, and from $0$ to $0.5-x$ for the second.  That shouldn't matter in this case, though, provided that the limits for both integrals are inverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
P(X+Y < 1/2) & = \int_{x=0}^{1/2} \int_{y=0}^{1/2-x} \left(24y-24xy-24y^2\right)
        \,dy\,dx \\
    & = \int_{x=0}^{1/2} \left.\left(12y^2-12xy^2-8y^3\right)\right]_{y=0}^{1/2-x}
        \,dx \\
    & = \int_{x=0}^{1/2} \left(2-9x+12x^2-4x^3\right) \,dx \\
    & = \left. \left(2x-\frac{9}{2}x^2+4x^3-x^4\right) \right]_{x=0}^{1/2} \\
    & = \frac{5}{16}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you show me how you got this because I keep messing this up. I have the limits the same as yours. Someone edited my original question incorrectly.

Comment: @Brian Tung  Do you sure about $\frac{5}{16}$

Comment: @Cardinal: Do you see an error?  If so, please fix or so indicate, thanks!

Comment: @BrianTung and would you correct my answer ?

Comment: I think you're just missing a $y$ in the integrand.

Comment: Becuase the Question has been changed

Comment: I was very bad typed, i dont recognized that y